# Google sign in is not working after signing Apk

Tags: android-studio, apk

I have signed my Apk using Android Studio but after signing Google auth using Firebase is not working in app but before app signing everything is working fine. I am unable to get what is wrong here; I am running app in Android Studio and it's working fine in emulator.

Comment: Do you have any failure messages when signing the Apk? Or what is your failure message in Google Auth? Readers will probably need more information to go on here.

Comment: No error message I have release app bundle and in play console also everything worked fine.

Comment: When I am trying to sign in it is saying Login failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is all I need to link my app signing SHA-1 certificate to firebase project.In Google play console after heading to Release management -> App signing for there copy App signing SHA-1 certificate and paste it in firebase project settings.It worked fine for me.

**THANKS**